# How Should the Json Output Look in Nlog?

Tags: json, nlog

I am using nlog json layout and took this from the example

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "NLog": {
            "IncludeScopes": false,
            "ParseMessageTemplates": true,
            "CaptureMessageProperties": true
        }
    },
    "NLog": {
        "autoreload": true,
        "internalLogLevel": "Info",
        "internalLogFile": "c:/temp/console-example-internal2.log",
        "throwConfigExceptions": true,
        "targets": {
            "console": {
                "type": "Console",
                "layout": "${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}"
            },
            "file": {
                "type": "AsyncWrapper",
                "target": {
                    "wrappedFile": {
                        "type": "File",
                        "fileName": "c:/temp/console-example2.log",
                        "layout": {
                            "type": "JsonLayout",
                            "Attributes": [
                                { "name": "timestamp", "layout": "${date:format=o}" },
                                { "name": "level", "layout": "${level}" },
                                { "name": "logger", "layout": "${logger}" },
                                { "name": "message", "layout": "${message:raw=true}" },
                                { "name": "properties", "encode": false, "layout": { "type": "JsonLayout", "includeallproperties": "true" } }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rules": [
            {
                "logger": "*",
                "minLevel": "Trace",
                "writeTo": "File,Console"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/examples/NetCore2/ConsoleExampleJsonConfig/appsettings.json

on this line I saw this `{ "name": "message", "layout": "${message:raw=true}" }` I changed it to false.

when I do this

```
var test = "Something";
logger.Info("This is what is stored in the variable: {var}", test);
```

I get

```
{ 
   "message": This is what is stored in the variable: \"Something\""
}
```

Why is it in quotes?

When I change raw to "true" I get

```
{ 
   "message": This is what is stored in the variable: {test}"
}
```

how do I just get "This is what is stored in the variable: Something"

Comment: NLog tries to follow the Message-Template specification: https://messagetemplates.org/ where you can try `"The variable {var:l}"` to get rid of quotes. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3556#issuecomment-523621069

Comment: cool, I will check that out. On a side now how do I log exceptions? I thought it would be ${exception:tostring} but that is not working

Comment: Make sure to provide the exception-object as first parameter. Ex. `logger.Info(ex, "Failed");`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Problem was for whatever reason I need to do a full like rebuild to get the changes to go through. Me just doing F5 was not cutting it. Had to do a rebuild then it kicked in.